# How to continue receiving numbers until a zero is entered and count total positive and negative numbers the user entered.in the textfield

Tags: javascript, html

More Details:

Program should receive a number and continue receiving numbers [from users input] until
a zero is entered. When a zero is entered, the program should output how many positive and how
many negative numbers have been entered, and then stop.

So far I've only been able to enter *one number* at a time in the textfield and only been able to output one value that is either positive or negative.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercise Two</title>
    <link href="ex2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ex2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Enter number (Press 0 to stop)
<input type="text" id="num">
<button onclick="check()">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function check(){

    let btnClear = document.querySelector('button');
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
 
    btnClear.addEventListener('click', () => {
        inputs.forEach(input =>  input.value = '');
});

    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
    var posCount = 0;
    var negCount = 0;

    if (x > 0) {
        posCount++;
    }else{
        negCount++;
    }
    

    alert("Positive numbers: " + posCount + "\nNegative numbers: " + negCount);
}
```

Comment: When you want it till a zero is entered then why is a submit button there?

Comment: I want to enter a random number a first (not 0) and submit it so it clears the textfield. So I can enter a new number.

Comment: you can clear the field through javascript

Comment: I placed the submit button there so I can clear the textfield in order to enter a new number. Once i enter enough random numbers I press 0 to terminate program and count all the positive and negative numbers which have been entered in the textfield.

Comment: @SeanD check my solution if its the one you want or I missed something?

Comment: Something smells like homework in here.  Anybody else smell that?

Comment: @MichaelChaney 

Comment: Yes this is correct thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

To achieve this, `you can create a positive and negative variable outside` of the count function and then check each input value; if the value entered zero, you can call your alert function and print the result.

Here is the working code:

```js
var posCount = 0;
var negCount = 0;

function printOutput () {
alert("Positive numbers: " + posCount + "\nNegative numbers: " + negCount);

}

function check(){

    let btnClear = document.querySelector('button');
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
 
    

    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
    document.getElementById("num").value = ''

    if (x > 0) {
        posCount++;
    }else if (x < 0){
        negCount++;
    } else {
      printOutput();
      // re-initiate value
      posCount = 0;
      negCount = 0;
    }

    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercise Two</title>
    <link href="ex2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ex2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Enter number (Press 0 to stop)
<input type="text" id="num">
<button id="submit-btn" onclick="check()">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This the question: ***How to continue receiving numbers until a zero is entered and count total positive and negative numbers the user entered.in the textfield***

Answer (score 0):

You could try appending the data to a hidden `input` element:

```js
function check() {

  let btnClear = document.querySelector('button');
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

  btnClear.addEventListener('click', () => {
    inputs.forEach(input => input.value = '');
  });

  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);

  var totals = document.querySelector("#totals");
  var posCount = totals.dataset.positives;
  var negCount = totals.dataset.negatives;

  if (x === 0) {
    alert("Positive numbers: " + posCount + "\nNegative numbers: " + negCount);
    totals.dataset.positives = 0;
    totals.dataset.negatives= 0;
  } else if (x > 0) {
    totals.dataset.positives = ++posCount;
  } else {
    totals.dataset.negatives= ++negCount;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Enter number (Press 0 to stop)</p>
<input type="text" id="num">
<input type="hidden" id="totals" data-positives='0' data-negatives='0'>
<button onclick="check()">Submit</button>
```